# Euclidean metric inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

The definition of Euclidean metric for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $d_k(x,y) = (\sum^{n}_{i=1}|x_i - y_i|^k)^{1/k}$ for any integer k from 1 to n. Now the inequality I would like to prove is
$$n^{-1}d_1(x,y) \le n^{-1/2}d_2(x,y)$$
My attempt is like this: $n^{-1}d_2(x,y) \le n^{-1/2}d_2(x,y) \le n^{-1/2}d_1(x,y) \le d_1(x,y)$. I am getting the shape of it but still haven't got the idea how to put $n^{-1}d_1(x,y)$ in between the left most two terms. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is only called the Euclidean metric when $k = 2$. Otherwise it's called the $\ell_p$ metric (for $p = k$). Anyway, use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Use the Schwarz, Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't follow your argument at all, but that is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\sum a_ib_i<\sqrt{\sum a_i^2}\sqrt{\sum b_i^2}$$
with $a_i=|x_i-y_i|$ and $b_i=1$, so that $\sqrt{\sum b_i^2}=\sqrt{n}$.